# How to find out electric field Intensity for a far distant point in COMSOL multi Physics

Tags: atomic-physics

I have a surface plot for which I would like to find the E (Electric field intensity) at a far field point marked in red on the plot.

Therefore I would like to calculate Ex and Ey, so that I can calculate the norm to get the E.

How can I do that using COMSOL ?

[image: surface_plot]

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?

Comment: I took a line cut at the desired y coordinate and then found Ex variation in it , similarly I took another line cut at particular x coordinate and then found the Ey variation along the lines , thank you the issue was solved . Still if there is any better way to do this please mention. :)